# I am attempting to create a forEach method in order to get a substring of each array

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a text file that looks like this: sciFi.png, posed.png, birdA.png, dolphin.png, horse.png, shake.png, loft.png, basement.png, avenger.png, friend.png

I'm importing that file to a js doc and attempting to create an array out of that file and then use the *forEach()* method to create a *substr()* for each array element to take off the '.png'
(so the output would be sciFi, posed, birdA, dolphin and so on).

Here is my code so far:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My fabulous document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo">
    <h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">change content</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="getImgButton.js">
</script>
</html>
```

**js**

```
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        pix = this.responseText;
        myPix = pix.split(",");      
        myPix.forEach(myFunction);
        function myFunction(myPix) {
         // var buttVal = myPix.substr(0,myPix.indexOf("."));
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "imageList.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

I know I'm probably way off but I'm trying to figure out what to put in myFunction() to get this to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the option to write modern JS instead, because your tooling can generate the ancient JS that IE11 still needs, or do you need an answer that actually uses IE11-compatible JS? (because it's less than a year away from "literally every version of IE is now officially dead" so modern JS is probably the way to go, but I figured I'd ask anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern way to write this:

```js
async function loadDoc() {
  const response = await fetch('imageList.txt');
  const body = await response.text();
  const images = body.split(',').map(
    fileName => fileName.split('.')[0]
  );
  console.log(images);
}
```

The errors in your original snippet has to do with how you called `forEach`:

```js
        const images = [];
        myPix.forEach(myFunction, function myFunction(item) {
          var buttVal = myPix.substr(0,myPix.indexOf("."));
          images.push(buttVal);
        });
```